# Trust anchor for certification path not found error with AeroGear PushPlugin and cordova android platform

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, ssl-certificate, aerogear

I am creating a **android**  application with **cordova** and **AeroGear PushPlugin**  which uses **https** for communication with the unified push server.I use a valid CA certification support (TLS1.2) in my server.

When executing with  `cordova run android` return this error in my device :

`error javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.`

knowing, i added the certificat in:

> platforms/android/res/raw/myCert.crt

And this tag in the config.xml:

```
  <platform name="android">
    <network-security-config>
        <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
            <trust-anchors>
                <certificates src="myCert.crt" />
            </trust-anchors>
        </base-config>
    </network-security-config>
    </platform>
```

I followed several solutions proposed but dosen't work for my case.

thanks for Help.

Comment: there is no suggestion !!

Comment: In which Android version are you testing? if it's 5.0 or greater, which webview version are you using? There were some versions having troubles connecting with trusted certificates because of a bug, but should be fixed on latest webview. I'm not sure what do you try to achieve by adding that to you config.xml, but that won't do anything to your app.

Comment: i use **android 6.0.0**, I used the documentation in this link below  : https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#CertificatePinning

Comment: As you use android 6, can you check your webview version? (Settings -> Apps -> Android System WebView). That link talks about res/xml/network_security_config.xml file, that's different from Cordova's config.xml, you will need a resource-file tag or a hook to create that file.

Comment: the problem was in my CA in my UPS server :) thakns for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was certificat generation problem in the UPS widfly server.

If you have certification authority **CA** delivered by trsut provider.

Follow the steps:

1- You must first convert the PEM certificate delivered by your provider to p12 with this command:

```
$ openssl pkcs12 -export -out yourCertificategenerate.p12 -inkey yourCertificatekey.key  -in certifacteDelivedFromProvider.pem -certfile yourCertificateFromProvider.pem // file contains -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- ... -----END CERTIFICATE-----)
```

2- create the local keystore with this commande will be (yourCertificategenerate.jks), and copy it to the standalone/configuration directory with this command:

```
$ keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass yourpassword -destkeypass yourpassword -destkeystore yourNewCertificateGenerate.jks -srckeystore yourCertificateGenerate.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -srcstorepass ""
```

To check the certification chain

```
openssl s_client -connect yourDomaine.com -debug
```

if all things is ok you should have something like this : 
[image]